# watson conversation after slots prompts, the original message's entities data are lost

Tags: watson-conversation

notice there are some changes in watson conversation lately.

in the past (that is like late december 2017), my conversation dialog uses slots to help catch context that is required in deciding my condition response.

e.g. i am asking "what i should eat for my dinner", and there should be a context for "$vegan" to decide what response i should be giving. and i have a entity call @meal that define breakfast,dinner,lunch.
assume that there is a new user, so conversation has no info on the $vegan context.

**in the past:**
when i ask "what should i eat for dinner". the slot will prompt the user "are you a vegan" and i reply "yes". and the message will be flow back to the response where it remember the original question has @entity:dinner, hence it will response base on $vegan @entity:dinner and reply accordingly.

**but lately it has changed:**
when i ask "what should i eat for dinner". the slot will prompt the user "are you a vegan" and i reply "yes". and the message will be flow back to the response but this time round, it will only remember the $vegan context, but the @entity doesn't seems to be available. hence my reply always falls to the "anything else" variant.

any idea if i have did anything wrong? or it is indeed a change in the watson conversation behavior?

Answer (score 1):

Entity is always checked for current input. Watson never remember previous entity after a new input. So if you have to use the entity later you have to store it in a context variable.